# How to remotely log out all web-based Gmail sessions from my Android phone

Tags: gmail, security

Can I remotely sign out all web sessions of Gmail from my Android phone?

[This question](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/1297/how-can-i-remotely-log-out-of-gmail) explains how to do this from the Gmail website with a standard web browser. This doesn’t work from my phone because when I visit the Gmail website with the browser in my phone, I am redirected to a mobile version so I can't access the "Activity on this Account" feature.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have found two ways to access the “Activity on this Account” feature from the builtin Android 4.0 web browser:

1. Select the “Request desktop site” option in the browser menu, then open https://mail.google.com — this way it will not redirect to the mobile site. Then use the “Details” link at the bottom of the page, as you would do from a computer.
2. Open the mobile version of Gmail, select the “menu button” at the top line (with three vertical lines) — it will open the list of your tags. At the bottom of this list you will see a line with “Gmail version: Mobile | Mobile (old) | Full”; select the ”Full” link to switch to the full Gmail version (it looks slightly different than what you get with the first way). Again, you should see the “Details” link at the bottom of the page, which leads to the “Activity on this Account” page.

Comment: For what it's worth, Chrome beta wouldn't accept the "Request desktop site" when I tried it.

Answer (score 1):

If "Request desktop site" is not working then you can always change the user agent string to  in browser options, it exists on the stock Android browser `menu -> more -> Settings -> Advanced Settings -> Select User Agent -> [select one which ends with Desktop]`

Currently I don't think "there's an app for that" :p

Answer (score 0):

Here is another working solution.

1. First login to your gmail account from a desktop and click on the "Details" link. This will open a new window. You will see an URL at the new window. Copy/store that URL (like: `https://mail.google.com/mail/u/0/?ui=2&ik=**********&view=ac`).
2. Login to your gmail account from your android browser (chrome). Now browse that URL from the brwoser (chrome).

You will get the button "Sign out of all other accounts". Click that. You are done!

Answer (score 0):

[image]
Yes, I did it now from android with desktop version.
It seems to be very easy. It works in Crome browser. Here it is:-
Select the “Request desktop site” option in the browser menu, then open https://mail.google.com — this way it will not redirect to the mobile site. Then use the “Details” link at the bottom of the page, as you would do from a computer.
Open the mobile version of Gmail, select the “menu button” at the top line (with three vertical lines) — it will open the list of your tags. At the bottom of this list you will see a line with “Gmail version: Mobile | Mobile (old) | Full”; select the ”Full” link to switch to the full Gmail version (it looks slightly different than what you get with the first way). Again, you should see the “Details” link at the bottom of the page, which leads to the “Activity on this Account” page.